# Using gdal_translate to convert 32-bit raster to byte is black

Tags: grass-gis, gdal-translate, imagery

I have a 32-bit float raster in GRASS. It is a single channel Sentinel 2 raster. I can export to geotiff with `r.out.gdal`:

```
g.region rast=orthoimage_red
r.out.gdal input=orthoimage_red output=orthoimage_red.tif
```

Note that there is a colortable even if I use the `-c` flag, not sure if that has something to do with it:

```
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=GRASS GIS 8.3.1 with GDAL 3.6.4
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Band 1 Block=21893x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = orthoimage_red
  NoData Value=nan
  Metadata:
    COLOR_TABLE_RULES_COUNT=255
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_0=0.000000e+00 6.566784e-03 68 1 84 68 2 86
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_1=6.566784e-03 1.313357e-02 68 2 86 69 4 87
    COLOR_TABLE_RULE_RGB_...
```

If I open the `Float32` single-channel geotiff in Photoshop it looks as expected. But if I try to convert to `byte`, the resulting image is all black.

I have tried many scaling options, but still always black. If I look at the histogram, there is like one value right around the black level. All of these commands create identical results:

```
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte orthoimage_red.tif orthoimage_red_byte.tif
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte -scale 0 255 orthoimage_red.tif orthoimage_red_byte.tif
gdal_translate -of GTiff -ot Byte -scale 0 4294967296 0 255 orthoimage_red.tif orthoimage_red_byte.tif
```

I tried 4294967296 because from what I can tell that is how many levels are available with `Float32` images.

I have not been able to export with `r.out.gdal` using a `Byte` format either (I get complete data loss error or the image is black for everything I've tried).

How can I convert a gray `Float32` raster exported with `r.out.gdal` to `Byte`?

Here is the output of `gdalinfo -stats`. I've omitted the color table.

```
Band 1 Block=21893x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
  Description = orthoimage_red.tif
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=1.571, Mean=0.093, StdDev=0.069
  NoData Value=nan
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=1.5705000162125
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0.092601572377886
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.068607425873615
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=6.471
```

Comment: Please include output of `gdalinfo -stats orthoimage_red.tif`

Comment: Thanks! Added the output but didn't include the color table or information already posted. Please let me know if I can provide anything else.

Comment: If I use 1.570 (the reported max) for the input max I get a viewable image. I thought that I had tried that before but apparently not! I thought gdal_translate was supposed to use the max value if one isn't specified but apparently not.